# Let $\lambda_n$ be the location of the $n^{th}$ positive root of $x = 1/\sin(x)$. Evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\lambda_n - n\pi\right)$

Tags: summation, roots

Consider the set of positive intersections between the functions $x$ and $1/\sin(x)$. These are shown as red dots in the image below:

[image]

Let $\lambda_n > 0$ be the $x$-coordinate of the $n^{th}$ such intersection, where $n$ starts at $0$ for convenience. There are a number of things which can be proven about this set of numbers (I can furnish proofs of these upon request):

1) As $n$ increases, $\lambda_n$ grows ever closer to $n\pi$. This follows from inspecting the graph.

2) $\lambda_n$ alternates which *side* of $n\pi$ it is on. First it is greater than, then less than, etc. (Also follows from the graph.)

3) As $n$ increases, $\lambda_n$ rapidly converges toward $n\pi + \frac{{(-1)}^n}{n \pi}$.

4) $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{\lambda_n}^2} = 1$

5) $\lambda_0$ is very close to $\frac{1+\cos(1)}{\cos(1)+\sin(1)} \approx 1.114$

I wish to evaluate the sum
$$
S = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\lambda_n \;-\; n\pi\right)\, .
$$
By the alternating series test and the conditions above, this sum converges. Numerically (Mathematica), I find that this converges to about $S \approx 0.837$. I'm wondering if there is a nice analytic solution. We shouldn't *necessarily* expect there to be one... but there *is* that solution for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{{\lambda_n}^2}$, and we wouldn't necessarily have expected that, either!

Comment: Interesting question! How did you evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/\lambda_n^2$?

Comment: @user1892304: the function $x\sin x-1$ is an entire even function with real roots only. Then $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{\lambda_n^2}$ can be computed in the same way Euler computed $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}$ from the Weierstrass product for the sine function.

Comment: However, the fact that $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{\lambda_n^2}$ has a nice closed form depends on the symmetry of a Weierstrass product. To consider $\lambda_n - \pi n$ breaks such symmetry, so I *would not* expect a nice closed form for $\sum_{n\geq 1}(\lambda_n -\pi n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Using series expansion around $x=n\pi$ and power series reversion,
$$S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\lambda_n - n\pi\right)=-\frac{\log (2)}{\pi }-\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_n \frac {\zeta(2k+1)}{\pi^{2k+1} }$$ where the first coefficients are
$$\left\{\frac{9}{8},\frac{1003}{384},\frac{123467}{15360},\frac{3054
   4383}{1146880},\frac{488084447}{5160960},\frac{2153154223}{61931
   52},\cdots\right\}$$

Comment: Thank you for your response to a rather old question! It would seem that this sum doesn't have a nice closed form, which doesn't surprise me.

Comment: @JohnBarber. It was a long time I wanted to work this problem. Cheers.